# Make jButton to Open a jFrame in the Existing Window

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

We have a problem with our quiz made in NetBeans. We would like to open our jFrame in an existing jFrame when we press the play Button.

[Here's our current look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuzS8.jpg)

Currently we are using this code for the button:

```
 private void PlayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Question1 s = new Question1 ();
        s.setVisible(true);
```

How can we open a jFrame in an existing window?

Comment: How about JavaFX? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an object to hold your buttons images and what not it would be easier to use jPanel inside the jframe. You just remove or add the required jPanel then. If you want a separate window for it though a new jframe is needed.